# IoT device(Raspbbery Pi) registration on Kaa Platform

Tags: iot, kaa

As i am new user on Kaa platform. 
i want to know basic information about following topics.

1. How should i register my IoT device on kaa Platform ? Is there any way to register it on your platform.

   2.I have one \"Raspberry Pi\" device with temperature sensor. I want to register it on your platform.

   3.Once it is registerd i want to see some real time graphs that will shows the temperature in specific period.

Please help us.

Thanks and regrads,
Ganesh Narvadkar.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Kaa 0.10 [documentation](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Welcome/). There are direct answers for 1) and 2) with examples and comments.

As per 3), Kaa 0.10 does not provide graphs out of the box. You will need to use [Data Collection](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Key-platform-features/Data-collection/) feature, setup a [Log appender](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Key-platform-features/Data-collection/#log-appenders) of your choice and use a 3-rd party software for real time graphs (e.g. [Grafana](https://grafana.com/))

Again, all the above (except Grafana) is described in the documentation's [Your first Kaa application](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Your-first-Kaa-application/).